# How to fetch data only for a particular user from a database with data multiple users in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am trying to display data from a database based on the logged in user in laravel.

If there is data for one user everything works well but if another user adds data to the table I get the error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Here is how I am getting the data in controller

```
    public function viewBookings() {

$allProducts = Booking::get()->where('client', Auth::user()->name);
$products = json_decode(json_encode($allProducts));
foreach ($products as $key => $val) {
    $service_name = Service::where(['id' => $val->service])->first();
    $service_fee = Charge::where(['id' => $val->charge])->first();
    $service_status = Status::where(['id' => $val->status])->first();
    $products[$key]->service_name = $service_name->name;
    $products[$key]->service_fee = $service_fee->total;
    $products[$key]->service_status = $service_status->name;
}
return view('client.booking.view_bookings')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

The error is indicated at this line

```
    $products[$key]->service_name = $service_name->name;
```

I have tested it by deleting the data for the other user and all works fine but If I return the other users data to the table I get that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest removing this line

```
    $products = json_decode(json_encode($allProducts));
```

and simply use

```
    $products = $allProducts;
```

since what you are doing with the json_decode is the one creating the problems